# Hierarchical List in SwiftUI with CoreData

Tags: list, swiftui, core-data, hierarchical-data

I am trying to implement hierarchical CoreData in a SwiftUI `List`. I created a new project in Xcode using CoreData and just added a parent(to-one)/children(t-many) relationship to the `Item` entity:
[image]

I use Codegen Manual/None for `Item` and created `NSManagedObject` subclasses for `Item`. I added an extension to return the children as an `Array` (so that I can use it in `List` for the `children:` parameter):

```
public var childrenArray: [Item]? {
    let set = children as? Set<Item> ?? []
    print(set)
    return set.sorted(by: { $0.id?.uuidString ?? "NO ID?" < $1.id?.uuidString ?? "NO ID?" })
}
```

for `Item`.

In the `ContentView.swift`, I changed it to use a `List` with the `children:` parameter to show my hierarchical data. I also changed the `@FetchRequest` so that only `Items` without a parent are obtained:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "parent == nil"), animation: .default) private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(Array(items), children: \.childrenArray) { item in
            NavigationLink {
                VStack {
                    Text(item.id!.uuidString)
                }
            } label: {
                Text(item.id!.uuidString)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        Text("Select an item")
    }
}

private func addItem() {
    withAnimation {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
        newItem.id = UUID()
        
        // Add a new item and make it a children of first new item
        let newItem2 = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem2.timestamp = Date()
        newItem2.id = UUID()
        
        newItem.addToChildren(newItem2)
        // ------------------------------------------------------

        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

The result works, but I get a down-chevron for the item that does not have children:
[image]

Reading [Apples doc about List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) I understand that the children array should be `nil` to tell the `List` to not show a chevron. But I can't figure out how to do that in the `childrenArray` function. How would I have to adopt the `childrenArray` function to get the right array so that the `List` will not show a chevron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the computed property return nil by using a `guard` statement and return nil if there are no children

```
 guard let set = children as? Set<Item>, set.isEmpty == false else { return nil }
```

Full code

```
extension Item {
    public var childrenArray: [Item]? {
        guard let set = children as? Set<Item>, set.isEmpty == false else { return nil }
        return set.sorted(by: { $0.id?.uuidString ?? "NO ID?" < $1.id?.uuidString ?? "NO ID?" })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joakim Danielson. That is what I was looking for. Just for completeness, the extension needs to comply to Identifiable protocol for the List to work.